# Matrix and Playa | Loop Through Row As Many Times as Playa Relationships that Exist

Tags: matrix, playa

I've run into a bit of a roadblock. I'm relating two channels via a Playa relationship. The two channels are 'positions' and 'locations'. The 'locations' channel contains a Matrix field with a Playa relationship.

[image]

Currently, I have template code that looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="locations" dynamic="no" disable="member_data"}
  {locations-listing search:locations-position="General Manager" limit="1"}
    {exp:playa:children channel="positions" category="26" disable="member_data" var_prefix="loc"}
    <div class="job-listing clearfix">
      <div class="cell-1">
        <div class="position column">
          {loc:title}
        </div>

        <div class="city column">
          {locations-city row_id="{row_id}"}
        </div>

        <div class="state column">
          {title}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {/exp:playa:children}
{/locations-listing}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

How do I get the output to loop through the first Matrix row 2 times (in the screenshot, there are 2 Playa relationships) before moving on to the next row (and repeat that process for each row).

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated!